# How to find out how large a city is the in the country (database)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table with two columns:

```
1: City
2: Inhabitants
```

I am trying to do a select that can tell that a specific city is the xth largest in the country.

I am stuck, but am thinking that I might have to use an array?

Comment: `largest` is based on the number of `Inhabitants`? Also how does a `city` relate to a `country`?

Comment: Yes "largest" is based on Inhabitants and there is only one country.

SO: value x is the x'nd largest of all the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use following sql query to get its position from the top.

```
select count(1) from table 
where Inhabitants >= 
     (select Inhabitants 
      from table where city = 'Delhi')
and city != 'Delhi';
```

Here we are checking count of the number of cities with Inhabitant greater than that of city